# @SessionAttributes, how to actually use it

Tags: java, spring

So after reading and watching videos for days I really don't understand how @SessionAttributes works.

I tried watching videos, reading blogs, myself trying and searching in the Spring docs.

`enter code here`@SessionAttributes(value="username")
`enter code here`@Controller
`enter code here`public class MainController { ...

and then...

`enter code here`@GetMapping (value="/login")

```
enter code here

public String loginUser(Model model, @SessionAttribute("user") User user, ...
```

and then inside the Mapping...:

```
... 
    `enter code here`else {

        // Welcome!

        loginUser = daoUser.findByUsername(loginUser.getUsername());
        user = loginUser;
```

It's simple, I'm using it wrong but it's what I saw some people do and it worked for them. Sorry for my newbieness, recently getting the hand of Spring.
I just want to store the username of the user or if it is possible actually I tried with the (long) id of each user so I can find it with it in each mapping.